# I have to enter the text in element in the page, but the page has four elements with same properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I have to enter the text in element in the page, but the page has four elements with same properties, I couldn't find unique locator, Using protractor angular js web page? can some one help with this?

Here is the webelements :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="size.quantity" class="isd-txt-btn ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-change="quantityChanged(size)" ng-disabled="readOnly">
```

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, why not just add  `id="textFieldId"` in your input tag, then call `document.getElementById('textFieldId').value ="Something"`in the Javascript.

Comment: The preferred way is not IDs, since IDs need to be unique, and it's easy to duplicate them accidentally. It may not matter in your context, but as an option, you can tag your elements with empty CSS classes and select on that (so yes, you'd use four empty CSS classes). I get that this seems like a hack (I really dislike it), but believe it or not it is the recommended approach over IDs. Another way is to do a "find" on the directive element for "input", which will give you back all the input elements as a dict. You can then select by index. Not great, but it works and keeps you away from IDs.

Comment: Uh...or just add a unique ID on the 4 text fields...

Comment: If there are 4 totally same elements on page you can try to use indexes

Comment: There is no need to add hackish "empty CSS classes". Indexes would work if you never move or add new elements. Just add a unique ID.

Comment: @obarakon QA might not have access to change `HTML` source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use element.all(locator).get(index) method to enter data into required field. Identify target input field index (either 0 or 1 or 2 or 3).

**Code**:

```
      element.all(locator).get(index).sendKeys("Test Data");
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one element that could be matched with your selector, try to match it by its index:

```
element.all(by.css('input[type="text"]')).get(2).sendKeys('someText');
```

Set proper index (starting from `0`) of target `input` to `get()`